# jQuery Version Download

Tags: jquery, download, version

I was wondering which download I need of jQuery: https://jquery.com/download/, because I'd like to start making [interactive websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877747/ideas-for-making-my-website-interactive).

On the download website there IS an explanation of all sorts of jQueries, but I don't understand anything of it. :D

> Downloading jQuery
>
> Compressed and uncompressed copies of jQuery files are available. The
>   uncompressed file is best used during development or debugging; the
>   compressed file saves bandwidth and improves performance in
>   production. You can also download a sourcemap file for use when
>   debugging with a compressed file. The map file is not required for
>   users to run jQuery, it just improves the developer's debugger
>   experience. As of jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 the //# sourceMappingURL comment
>   is not included in the compressed file.
>
> To locally download these files, right-click the link and select "Save
>   as..." from the menu. link jQuery 1.x
>
> The jQuery 1.x line had major changes as of jQuery 1.9.0. We strongly
>   recommend that you also use the jQuery Migrate plugin if you are
>   upgrading from pre-1.9 versions of jQuery or need to use plugins that
>   haven't yet been updated. Read the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide and the
>   jQuery 1.9 release blog post for more information.
>
> Download the compressed, production jQuery 1.11.2
>
> Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 1.11.2
>
> Download the map file for jQuery 1.11.2
>
> jQuery 1.11.2 release notes link jQuery 2.x
>
> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. All the notes in the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade
>   Guide apply here as well. Since IE 8 is still relatively common, we
>   recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8
>   users are visiting the site. Please read the 2.0 release notes
>   carefully.
>
> Download the compressed, production jQuery 2.1.3
>
> Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 2.1.3
>
> Download the map file for jQuery 2.1.3
>
> jQuery 2.1.3 release notes

Thank You,
HydraCles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want the latest available release of v1 or v2. If you need to support IE8 or earlier, use v1 (at the moment, v1.11.2). If you don't, use v2 (at the moment, v2.1.3).

For development, you may want the uncompressed version of jQuery (although many people just use the compressed version even in dev). For production, you'll want the compressed version, or to load it from one of the CDNs that provides access to it (rather than hosting it yourself). I hesitate to point you back at the page you said you didn't understand, but there's more information about using jQuery from a CDN [here](https://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn).

Comment: @HydraCles: For production, yes.

Comment: @HydraCles: **Yes**, that's why I said *"For development...uncompressed"* and *"For production...compressed"* above.

Comment: @HydraCles: **For development: Uncompressed** That's the third time I've said it.